# Make users logged in another site (which is of a different domain)

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, authentication, cookies

I am working on internal website, which is used only within the company. The requirement for one of its pages is to log-in to our vendor sites (which are all on different domains).

For this I open these vendor sites within an iframe of the internal website.

Say,

- Internal site: us.com
- Vendor sites: foo.com, bar.com

On us.com/openvendor , there are two options: foo and bar. When a user clicks on foo, the iframe within the page opens foo.com in **signed in** state.

To achieve this, I replicate the login form of foo.com and post all the required parameters like username, password etc. to foo.com's page. I have all the usernames and passwords of different vendors stored in database.

Why do I do this? Because we don't want the users of this site(mostly our CRM team) to know the passwords (lest they use it to do unwanted and untracked transactions) and the activities done through us.com is recorded and saved.

So essentially, we enable users to login to any vendor site, just by clicking on a link.

This was working perfectly fine until one day, when I had to add a new vendor site which doesn't post an html form for authentication. This site (say whattodo.com) makes an ajax call to a url with login credentials, which returns back an authentication cookie. This cookie is then set by the site to make the user logged in.

Now how can I make my end users login to whattodo.com on a click?

- I cannot make the ajax call to whattodo.com
- Even if I overcome the above problem by storing the auth cookie value in my database and updating it monthly(ya that's when the cookie expires), I cannot set this cookie under whattodo.com domain in the user's browsers.

Please suggest a possible solution.

And please feel free to edit the title. I'm sure there's a better one to summarize the question.

Comment: Can you use JSONP to execute the AJAX call to whattodo.com?

Comment: Ummm please don't? Firstly any half way tech savey member of your staff will be able to get the password for your vendor sites, just buy popping up the network tab in their browser. Secondly if any of your vendor sites update to disallow XSRF (which they should) you will be broken.

Comment: @DavidWaters I know the solution is a hack and yes I'm aware of the fact that end users can find out the passwords anyway(say by using any basic browser dev tools and seeing the POST parameters). But its still better than giving out plain text passwords isn't it?
But I need to do something because this is the requirement :(

Comment: @BrianFlanagan Even if I do that and get the cookie. How do I set it on whattodo.com? We cannot set a cookie on a different domain than the one on which script is executing.

Comment: @DavidWaters You're right.  I misinterpreted the requirements and assumed the passwords were specific to individuals instead of company-wide.